# Function to Convert Value From One Type To Another While Catching Errors

Tags: vb.net

I'm new to vb.net and still have lots to learn.  This works, but I'm sure there's an easier way to do it.  Could someone point me in the right direction?  Thanks.

```
Public Function GetValue(passVal As Object, valType As Type, errorVal As Object) As Object
    Try
        Select Case valType
            Case GetType(String)
                Return CType(passVal, String)
            Case GetType(Date)
                Return CType(passVal, Date)
            Case GetType(Decimal)
                Return CType(passVal, Decimal)
            Case GetType(Integer)
                Return CType(passVal, Integer)
            Case GetType(Boolean)
                Return CType(passVal, Boolean)
            Case Else
                MsgBox("Type Not Recognized")
                Return errorVal
        End Select
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return errorVal
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: What would you use this for?  Since the return type is `As Object` whatever that code returns gets boxed.  There is likely an easier way to do thie upstream from here.

Comment: I second that. I know it's frustrating when you ask questions and instead of answering people recommend not doing what you're trying to do. But since you're learning it's better to head it off. The trick is to write code so that you already know what types objects are and you don't have to inspect them. Basically, 99.9% of the time you don't want functions with `object` as a parameter type.

Comment: $.02 from someone who spent over five years writing VB.NET: If at all possible, switch to C# before you get too far. There are more code samples in C#, it makes some things easier to write, and once you're used to the {braces} and semicolons other languages like JavaScript suddenly become much easier. I switched over about three years ago but I wish I'd done it sooner.

Comment: Can't you just do `return CType(passVal, valType)` within the error handler?

Comment: Thanks for your responses!  I found that when I try to pull values from my SQL database, they don't always convert into the correct value type.  For example, depending on my database structure, dates can read as (1) an actual date, (2) '0000-00-00', or (3) DBNull.Value.  If it's (2) or (3) it throws an exception when I try to convert it to a date.  Same thing with decimals.  It will throw an exception when it tries to convert DBNull.Value or an empty string.  Rather than having dozens and dozens of try/catch statements, I was hoping to take this shortcut.  Any thoughts?

Comment: And Stuart, I tried that but it throws a compile error.  I'm not sure why though.  So this was my work around in the meantime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply implement it using Generic type function. Generic functions are powerful feature of language and suitable for cases like this.

## example:

```
Function GetValue(Of T)(value As Object, defaultValue As Object) As T  
    Try  
        Return CTypeDynamic(Of T)(value)  
    Catch ex As Exception  
        Return defaultValue  
    End Try  
End Function
```

and use it:
        dim val as string=getValue(of string)(10,"")

Comment: @bdbcse  You're welcome. I glad I could help!  consider denote correct answer by marking as `Accepted`. this helps other peoples to to find their answer when visiting this page.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Convert method, like so:
(for String to Integer)

Dim i As Integer = Convert.ToInt32("45") ' This will return 45.

It also works with double, decimal, dateTime (date), int16, int64, etc.
Basically, most data types.